# C# Excel Interop: How to set cells height and width in pixels?

Tags: c#, office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop

I will not intentionally post any codes in this question as it is not needed to answer this question, for some reasons I need to set Height and Width of the cells in my worksheet via pixels value and not the standard `activeWorksheet.Rows.RowHeight` which accept standard value.
How can I successfully set Height and Width of a cell via pixels? Thanks.

Comment: `pixels = points * DPI / 72` could be reversed to `points = pixels / DPI * 72`

Comment: @JeremyThompson thanks for the reply, where and how I get the DPi?

Comment: Mate, simply Google "c# get DPI"

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes, you are right lol :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula:

`pixels = points * DPI / 72`

can be reversed to:

`points = pixels / DPI * 72`

This way you can set Row Height using pixels.

To [get the DPI in C# see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6844216/495455).

Comment: But the question is how you set it in Excel Interop: excWorksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = pixels / DPI * 72; is way to many pixels when you put your mouse over the column in excel.

Comment: @JohnKurtz you're talking about Column width, the question is about RowHeight.

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed that they would be measured the same way! Any insights on how the Columns Width IS handled? Title asks about height and width.

Comment: For Arial 10, I found a good approximation to be: excWorksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = 0.14286f * (pixels - 5);